# Makefile shared library error

Tags: linux, makefile

I was doing makefile test for creating static library and creating dynamic library from it. I have foo.h foo.c bar.c and main.c files in my directory.
I wrote a Makefile as follows:

#This makefile demonstrate the shared and static library creation.

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -fPIC
CFLAGS1 = -Wall
inc = /home/betatest/Public/implicit-rule-archive

all : foo.o bar.o libfoo.a libfoo.so run

foo.o: foo.c foo.h
        @echo "Making the foo.o"
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o  $@

bar.o : bar.c foo.h
        @echo "Making the bar.o"
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

libfoo.a(foo.o bar.o) : foo.o bar.o
        ar cr $@ $^

libfoo.so : libfoo.a
        $(CC) -shared -o $@ $^

run : main.c
        $(CC) -L$(inc) $(CFLAGS1) -o $@ $< -lfoo

.PHONY : clean

clean :
        -rm -f *.o run libfoo.*
```

while making it gives the following the following errors:

```
Making the foo.o
cc -c -Wall -Werror -fPIC  foo.c -o  foo.o
Making the bar.o
cc -c -Wall -Werror -fPIC  bar.c -o bar.o
make: *** No rule to make target 'libfoo.a', needed by 'all'.  Stop.
```

I have written the archive statement as :

```
libfoo.a(foo.o bar.o) : foo.o bar.o
        ar cr $@ $^
```

from this to:

```
libfoo.a(*.o) : *.o
        ar cr $@ $^
```

Can I write the statement like this because in both the cases the error is the same. 
I don't understand where I am going wrong. Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `libfoo.a(foo.o bar.o)` you want plain `libfoo.a : foo.o bar.o`.

---

Another thing is that `.a` files are normally built for linking against the final executable, hence object files for `.a` are compiled as position-dependent code. Shared libraries, on the other hand, require code compiled as position independent.

Hence, you can:

1. Get rid of `libfoo.a`.
2. Produce header dependencies automatically.
3. Establish complete dependencies on your targets so that `make -j` works robustly.
4. Set rpath so that `run` always finds `libfoo.so` in its directory.

This way:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror 
LDFLAGS = -L/home/betatest/Public/implicit-rule-archive -Wl,-rpath,'$$ORIGIN'

all : run

run : main.o libfoo.so
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

libfoo.so : CFLAGS += -fPIC # Build objects for .so with -fPIC.
libfoo.so : foo.o bar.o
    $(CC) -shared -o $@ $^

# Compile any .o from .c. Also make dependencies automatically.
%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -MD -MP $<

# Include dependencies on subsequent builds.
-include $(wildcard *.d)

.PHONY : all clean

clean :
    -rm -f *.o *.d run libfoo.*
```

Comment: I made the changes but now the problem is :`cc -c -Wall -Werror -fPIC  foo.c -o  foo.o
cc -c -Wall -Werror -fPIC  bar.c -o bar.o
ar cr libfoo.a foo.o bar.o
cc -shared -o libfoo.so libfoo.a
cc -L/home/betatest/Public/implicit-rule-archive  -Wall -o run main.c -lfoo
/tmp/ccGKSd1I.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `foo'
main.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `bar'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:27: recipe for target 'run' failed
make: *** [run] Error 1` If i manually make .so files from .o files it works fine. but here it gives error.

Comment: You do not have symbols `foo` and `bar` defined in your .so.

Comment: Thanks @ MaximEgorushkin sir !!!!!!!! That worked . I want to know that in any assignment we write multiple flags with space separated list but in LDFLAGS you have used comma. So does it acceptable or it has some special case. And one more thing ORIGIN is the origin function for checking the type of variable. Please reply... Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks @MaximEgorushkin !!!!!! It have clear many doubt of mine. I am doing for the first time.